# Getting Blob Counts based on query in Azure BlobStorage

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

In the below code, how can I find number of result based on Tags? I want exact count.

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(getConnectionString).buildClient();

blobServiceClient.findBlobsByTags("\"name\"='Raj'").forEach(blob -> System.out.printf("BlobName: %s%n", blob.getName()));
```

Comment: Can you try something like `int blobsCount = blobServiceClient.findBlobsByTags(""name"='Raj'").getValue().size();`?

Comment: @GauravMantri Not getting getValue() after findBlobByTags, Its because the return type of findBlobsByTags is PagedIteratble<TaggedBlobItem>